# Apache + Redhat: Apache not detecting any conf file even though it's there?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

So I have a symlink to my config file in my sites-available, and a symlink to that in my sites-enabled folder.

```
    [emai@511863-web3 sites-available]$ ls
    mysite-staging.conf
    [emai@511863-web3 sites-available]$ cd ..
    [emai@511863-web3 httpd]$ ls
    conf  conf.d  logs  modules  run  sites-available  sites-enabled
    [emai@511863-web3 httpd]$ cd sites-enabled/
    [emai@511863-web3 sites-enabled]$ ls
    mysite-staging.conf
    [emai@511863-web3 sites-enabled]$ more mysite-staging.conf
    <VirtualHost *:80>

      RailsEnv "staging"
      RackEnv "staging"     

        ServerName mysite-staging.nettheory.com
      ServerAlias mysite-authorize-staging.nettheory.com

      DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/current/public
      ErrorLog logs/mysite-staging/error_log
      CustomLog logs/mysite-staging/access_log combined


      <Directory /usr/local/www/mysite-staging/current/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

However, when I check the syntax, Apache doesn't detect anything.

```
    [emai@511863-web3 sites-enabled]$ apachectl -S
    VirtualHost configuration:
    Syntax OK
    [emai@511863-web3 sites-enabled]$ /usr/sbin/httpd -S
    VirtualHost configuration:
    Syntax OK
```

I restart apache and try to go to my site through a browser, but it only gives me the default redhat linux page, and doesn't allow me to go on the site because I'm guessing it's not up. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sites-enabled` is a Debian-ism, which isn't used or configured by default in RHEL.  Did you create that directory?

You can drop your site file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` to have it work.  Or, you can get the configuration loading in `sites-enabled` by adding a line to the bottom of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/*
```

Comment: That include line worked perfectly. Thanks for the info!